# Apache URL Rewrite for 404 pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We are moving webservers, however all the content hasn't migrated yet.  What I would like to do is whenever someone encounters a 404, I'd like to redirect them to the old server with the same path they were trying.

For example:

User visits: http://new.test.com/department/something.php

This would result in a 404, so I'd like to automatically send them here:
http://old.test.com/department/something.php

Can I do this with a .htaccess, or do should I use PHP scripting on a custom 404 page on new.test.com to do the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file on new site:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Request is on new host 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?new\.test\.com$ [NC]
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# redirect to old host URL
RewriteRule . http://old.test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, worked perfectly. Super fast response too!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://old.test.com/department/something.php
```

You can use a local path and the 404 status code is sent. But if you give an absolute URI like above a 302 status code (temporary redirect) is sent.

But this works only for a fixed destination path.

But you may do it in two steps using ErrorDocument to select the 404 requests and a following redirect to send the destination url:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404_to_oldsite/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/404_to_oldsite/  http://master.example.com{REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI}  [R,L]
```

This needs the module `mod_rewrite` to be enabled.

If a page is called and could not be found it is redirected to the local url and this local url will then be redirected to your old site. And the browser should get the page from there.